# fine tuned model being pushed to huggingface repo doesn't have config.json

Tags: huggingface, llama

I am using autotrain to train the llama model and push it to my huggingface repo.

```
!autotrain llm --train --project_name my-llm-test --model meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf --data_path test --use_peft --use_int4 --learning_rate 2e-4 --train_batch_size 12 --num_train_epochs 3 --trainer sft --push_to_hub --repo_id myrepo/test
```

After that I tried to use it

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM,AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("myrepo/test", use_auth_token=True)
test_model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("myrepo/test", use_auth_token=True)
```

But I got the error like below. I don't know why it doesn't have the config.json file because I just used the autotrain and pushed the model. I am quite new to huggingface. Would you mind giving me a help? Thanks!

```
OSError: myrepo/test does not appear to have a file named config.json.
```

Comment: did you find  any solution ? your advice will be appreciate

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the restricted resources of the free Colab environment, which led to the script being terminated by Colab. However, upon running the script on a higher-capacity instance with a Colab Pro subscription, the script executed without any issues.

Comment: please give use the solution ,not advice

Answer (score 0):

PEFT just trains the adapter, you need to merge with the base model. You may use this space, for example:
https://huggingface.co/spaces/autotrain-projects/llm-merge-adapter